# Visual Studio Online Development "Add link" button not loading

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Has anyone has this issue with visual studio online whereby the "Add link" button for a task is not loading?  I am not certain what happened, but I logged in today and it won't work. [image: Screenshot showing link button that won't load]

Answer (score 0):

No, the field won’t be missed unless the **development is hiden from layout**.

You can have  a try by opening a WIT (such as a task) -> `…` button -> customize.

[image]

It will take you to VSTS process layout page. You can click the `…` button for Development -> Hide from layout.

[image]

Then you can open a task, the option Add link for development won’t be shown.

[image]

So the Development mainly set as Hide from layout by your team members when you were open a task.